# How to write Laravel Excel Import test with custom file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I tried this:

```
public function test_import_cards_job_created()
{
    Excel::fake();

    $file = new UploadedFile(
        base_path('tests/data/import/test_file.csv'),
        'test_file.csv',
        'text/csv',
        null,
        true
    );

    $this->actingAs(User::first())
        ->post('/api/import', [
            'csvFile' => $file
        ]);

    Excel::assertQueued('test_file.csv');
}
```

But the test fails saying, `test_file.csv is not queued for export on disk default`

So, how to write Laravel Excel Import test with custom file?

Comment: Hi, were you ever able to find a solution for this? I've run into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You're not pointing to the explicit filePath in `Excel::assertQueued('test_file.csv');`. What you need to do, like what you're doing in `new UploadFile` is use the `base_path` in `Excel::assertQueued`.

For example:

```
Excel::assertQueued(base_path('tests/data/import/test_file.csv'), function(UsersImport $import) {
    dd($import);
});
```

This should work.